# Cut with CTRL+MINUS key combination

Tags: edges

I watched a video explaining how to cut a door into a cylinder by using a cube. See video here => https://streamable.com/qjp0xu
The cut is created using the CTRL+Minus key. I tried to recreate that but nothing happened. Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as you can see in the video:

[image]

he is using the BTool.

So you first have to check on the add-on in your preferences:

[image]

and check the hotkeys for that.

[image]

Test:

[image]

CTRL-SHIFT-minus

[image]

CTRL-Minus

[image]

Comment: Thanks for solving this for me guys. Cheers.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 7):

You need to enable the Bool Tool add-on beforehand to get this shortcut. It's shipped for free with Blender. Go to Options > Preferences > Add-ons and look for Bool Tool in the list or type it in the search bar in the top right, then enable the checkbox.

If I may, as a general advice you should train yourself with the basic features of Blender before diving into poweruser add-ons. The Bool Tool add-on is a shortcut to simplify the boolean modelling approach.

You can achieve the same result by adding a Boolean modifier to the Cylinder, and picking the other object as the target.

[image]

Then it also automatically deactivates rendering of the cutter object and displays it as Bounds :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think in Blender 2.9 it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>